# I created a slideshow using jQuery and the slideshow stays in the middle of the screen when I scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

http://magician.sdf-eu.org/zee/Click%20This%20One%20To%20View%20What%20I%20Have%20So%20Far.html

Thanks a lot for your help, stack overflow.

CSS is here

http://magician.sdf-eu.org/zee/css/showcss.css

jQuery source code is included in the page.

Comment: So... what's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your ".center" class has position of fixed. Try switching it to absolute:

```
.center{
   //other styles
   position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the `position:fixed` to `position:absolute` at your `.center` class

```
.center
{

    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-490px;

}
```

Note :at fixed position the element is positioned relative to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

or instead you can use this

```
.center{
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

a bit less code :)

Answer (score 0):

badAdviceGuy is right, it's because your position is fixed.  This tells the item to stay on this part of this page no matter what the scroll value is.

However, you shouldn't even need to set an absolute or fixed position here.

A nice fix for you would be to remove all of the styles you currently have set on your center tag.
Then style it like this:

```
.center{
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

We use 980px, because this is the width of your images/image container and most likely always will be, at least on this project.

And margin: 0 auto, basically tells your center container to add 0px on the top and bottom margins, but set the left and right margins to the same px amount so that the element is centered within it's container.

Comment: Please, feel free to contact me if you would like some help learning html/css as i'd be glad to help someone who is eager enough to learn.